# Condicion en php con function y strtotime no me valida un periodo de fechas

Tags: php, html

Tengo una fecha que deseo condicionar. 27-12-2016. Deseo revisar si dentro del periodo de fechas del 20-12-2015 al 20-12-2016 se cumple o no, así como también del 20-12-2016 al 20-12-2017.  En el caso de la primer periodo 2015-2016 no se cumple pues ya paso la fecha. Pero si se debe cumplir al periodo 2016-2017 y sin embargo me indica que esta fuera de periodo.

Aqui la pantalla y el codigo.

[image: Pantalla]

También anexo el código en `PHP`

```
<?php

$hoy               = date('d-m-Y');
$fi                = date("20-12-2001");
$fecha_ingreso     = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fi));
$anio_actual       = date("Y");
$fecha_aniversario = date("d-m-" . $anio_actual . "", strtotime($fi));

echo "Fecha de Ingreso: " . $fecha_ingreso . "</br>";
echo "Fecha de Aniversario en el año 2016: " . $fecha_aniversario . "</br>";
echo "Comparar si el dia de hoy " . $hoy . " el empleado cumple Aniversario:  </br>";

if ($fecha_aniversario == $hoy) {
    echo "Hoy " . $hoy . " es su aniversario </br>";
} else {
    echo "Hoy " . $hoy . " no es su aniversario </br>";
}

$periodo2015 = strtotime('-1 year', strtotime($fecha_aniversario));
$periodo2015 = date('d-m-Y', $periodo2015);

$periodo2017 = strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($fecha_aniversario));
$periodo2017 = date('d-m-Y', $periodo2017);



echo " Comparar si " . $hoy . "  cumple el rango de :" . $periodo2015 . " al periodo " . $fecha_aniversario . " </br> ";


$fecha1 = new DateTime($hoy);
$fecha1 = $fecha1->format("d-m-Y");

$f2015 = new DateTime($periodo2015);
$f2015 = $f2015->format("d-m-Y"); //=> 2015

$f2016 = new DateTime($fecha_aniversario);
$f2016 = $f2016->format("d-m-Y"); //=> 2016

$f2017 = new DateTime($periodo2017);
$f2017 = $f2017->format("d-m-Y"); //=2017


function comprobarPeriodo20152016($fecha1, $f2015, $f2016)
{

    return $fecha1 >= $f2015 && $fecha1 <= $f2016;
}


if (comprobarPeriodo20152016($fecha1, $f2015, $f2016)) {

    echo " " . $fecha1 . " Esta dentro del periodo " . $f2015 . "-" . $f2016 . "</br>";

} else {

    echo " " . $fecha1 . " Esta fuera del periodo " . $f2015 . "-" . $f2016 . "</br>"; // <= Resultado
}

echo "</br>";

echo " Comparar si " . $hoy . "  cumple el rango de :" . $fecha_aniversario . " al periodo " . $periodo2017 . " </br> ";

function comprobarPeriodo20162017($fecha1, $f2016, $f2017)
{

    return $fecha1 >= $f2016 && $fecha1 <= $f2017;
}


if (comprobarPeriodo20162017($fecha1, $f2016, $f2017)) {

    echo " " . $fecha1 . " Esta dentro del periodo " . $f2016 . "-" . $f2017 . "</br>";

} else {

    echo " " . $fecha1 . " Esta fuera del periodo " . $f2016 . "-" . $f2017 . "</br>"; // <= Resultado
}

echo "</br>";

?>
```

La primera condición se cumple. No esta dentro del periodo 2015-2016
La segunda deberia de cumplirse. Esta dentro del periodo 2016-2017 y no lo hace
Gracias por sus comentarios son bienvenidos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que utilizas dos funciones para hacer lo mismo. La idea de las funciones es que si se repite el algoritmo o el procedimiento y solo cambian los valores sea haga una SOLA función y que se le pase en los parámetros los diferentes valores. 
Unifique y cambie un poco la función que hace la comprobación de periodos, convirtiendo a timestamp las tres fechas y luego se hace la comparación.

Te dejo el script completo.

```
<?php

$hoy               = date('d-m-Y');
$fi                = date("20-12-2001");
$fecha_ingreso     = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fi));
$anio_actual       = date("Y");
$fecha_aniversario = date("d-m-" . $anio_actual . "", strtotime($fi));

echo "Fecha de Ingreso: " . $fecha_ingreso . "</br>";
echo "Fecha de Aniversario en el año 2016: " . $fecha_aniversario . "</br>";
echo "Comparar si el dia de hoy " . $hoy . " el empleado cumple Aniversario:  </br>";

if ($fecha_aniversario == $hoy) {
    echo "Hoy " . $hoy . " es su aniversario </br>";
} else {
    echo "Hoy " . $hoy . " no es su aniversario </br>";
}

$periodo2015 = strtotime('-1 year', strtotime($fecha_aniversario));
$periodo2015 = date('d-m-Y', $periodo2015);

$periodo2017 = strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($fecha_aniversario));
$periodo2017 = date('d-m-Y', $periodo2017);



echo " Comparar si " . $hoy . "  cumple el rango de :" . $periodo2015 . " al periodo " . $fecha_aniversario . " </br> ";


$fecha1 = new DateTime($hoy);
$fecha1 = $fecha1->format("d-m-Y");

$f2015 = new DateTime($periodo2015);
$f2015 = $f2015->format("d-m-Y"); //=> 2015

$f2016 = new DateTime($fecha_aniversario);
$f2016 = $f2016->format("d-m-Y"); //=> 2016

$f2017 = new DateTime($periodo2017);
$f2017 = $f2017->format("d-m-Y"); //=2017


function comprobarPeriodos($fecha_actual, $fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin){
        $inicio_ts = strtotime($fecha_inicio);
        $fin_ts = strtotime($fecha_fin);
        $fecha_actual_ts = strtotime($fecha_actual);
        return (($fecha_actual_ts >= $inicio_ts) && ($fecha_actual_ts <= $fin_ts));
    }


if (comprobarPeriodos($fecha1, $f2015, $f2016)) {

    echo " " . $fecha1 . " Esta dentro del periodo " . $f2015 . "-" . $f2016 . "</br>";

} else {

    echo " " . $fecha1 . " Esta fuera del periodo " . $f2015 . "-" . $f2016 . "</br>"; // <= Resultado
}

echo "</br>";

echo " Comparar si " . $hoy . "  cumple el rango de :" . $fecha_aniversario . " al periodo " . $periodo2017 . " </br> ";


if (comprobarPeriodos($fecha1, $f2016, $f2017)) {

    echo " " . $fecha1 . " Esta dentro del periodo " . $f2016 . "-" . $f2017 . "</br>";

} else {

    echo " " . $fecha1 . " Esta fuera del periodo " . $f2016 . "-" . $f2017 . "</br>"; // <= Resultado
}

echo "</br>";

?>
```

[image: Resultado]